# Hartshorne problem III.4.4

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Again I'm stuck on a problem in Hartshorne! In this problem we are supposed to show that if we take the limit of all coverings in on a topological space then the Cech cohomology agrees with derived functor cohomology in degree 1. I'm stuck on part (c) but maybe my error lies in something I did in parts (a) or (b) so let me explain what I've done so far (sorry for the wall of text, I have highlighted my questions):

In part (a) we define a refinement of coverings $\mathfrak{U}=(U_i)_{i\in I}$, $\mathfrak{V}=(V_j)_{j\in J}$ to be a map $\lambda:J\to I$ of the indexing sets such that $V_j\subset U_{\lambda(j)}$. For any refinement we get a map $\breve{H}^i(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{F})\to \breve{H}^i(\mathfrak{V},\mathcal{F})$. Indeed we have a chain map $\varphi:\breve{C}^\bullet(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{F})\to \breve{C}^\bullet(\mathfrak{V},\mathcal{F})$ which is defined in degree $d$ by

$$\varphi(\eta)_{j_0...j_d}=\eta_{\lambda(j_0)...\lambda(j_d)}|_{V_{j_0...j_d}}.$$

In fact this map comes from a chain map of complexes of sheaves $\breve{\mathscr{C}}^\bullet(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{F})\to \breve{\mathscr{C}}^\bullet(\mathfrak{V},\mathcal{F})$ where the degree $d$ map is defined by using the formula above on any open subset.

**Then Hartshorne claims that the coverings of $X$ form a partially ordered set which I don't agree with as we can have non-identity refinements of a covering. However, the coverings of $X$ do form a small category (if we don't allow any indexing set for the coverings) and we can take the colimit of the groups $\breve{H}^i(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{F})$**

In part (b) we have to show that the natural maps $\breve{H}^i(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{F})\to H^i(X,\mathcal{F})$ are compatible with refinements. To see this, let $\mathcal{I}^\bullet$ be an injective resolution of $\mathcal{F}$. We note that the two chain maps $\breve{\mathscr{C}}^\bullet(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{F})\to \mathcal{I}^\bullet$ we get from the following diagram
$$\breve{\mathscr{C}}^\bullet(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{F})\to \mathcal{I}^\bullet$$
$$\downarrow{}{}\quad\quad\quad\downarrow=$$
$$\breve{\mathscr{C}}^\bullet(\mathfrak{V},\mathcal{F})\to \mathcal{I}^\bullet$$
are chain homotopic and therefore induce the same map after applying global sections and then taking homology.

Now it's part (c) that I'm stuck on. We have to show that the natural map $\lim_{\mathfrak{U}}\breve{H}^1(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{F})\to H^1(X,\mathcal{F})$ is an isomorphism. Following the hint we embed $\mathcal{F}$ into a flasque sheaf $\mathcal{G}$ and consider the short exact sequence
$$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad0\to \mathcal{F}\to \mathcal{G}\to \mathcal{R}\to 0.\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(*)$$
We construct a short exact sequence of complexes of groups
$$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad0\to \breve{C}^\bullet(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{F})\to\breve{C}^\bullet(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{G})\to D^\bullet(\mathfrak{U})\to 0\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(**)$$
simply by taking $D^i(\mathfrak{U})=\breve{C}^i(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{F})/\breve{C}^i(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{G})$. We note that the groups $D^i$ are global sections of the presheaf $\mathcal{R'}:U\mapsto \breve{\mathscr{C}}^i(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{F})(U)/\breve{\mathscr{C}}^i(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{G})(U)$ and note that $\mathcal{R}$ is the sheaf associated to $\mathcal{R}'$. The canonical map $\mathcal{R}'\to \mathcal{R}$ induces a chain map $D^\bullet(\mathfrak{U})\to \breve{C}^\bullet(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{R})$ and it induces a map in cohomology $\alpha:H^0(D^\bullet(\mathfrak{U}))\to \breve{H}^0(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{R})=\Gamma(X,\mathcal{R})$. From the sequences $(*)$ and $(**)$ we get two long exact sequences of cohomology and the maps $\alpha$ fit into connect the two:
$$0\to \Gamma(X,\mathcal{F})\to\Gamma(X,\mathcal{G})\to H^0(D^\bullet(\mathfrak{U}))\to \breve{H}^1(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{F})\to 0$$
$$\quad\downarrow\quad\quad=\downarrow\quad\quad\quad=\downarrow\quad\quad\quad\quad\alpha\downarrow\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$$
$$0\to\Gamma(X,\mathcal{F})\longrightarrow\Gamma(X,\mathcal{G})\longrightarrow \Gamma(X,\mathcal{R})\longrightarrow H^1(\mathcal{F})\to 0\quad.$$
**From here I wanted to show that $\alpha$ is an isomorphism and that the top row remains exact in the limit which would solve the problem by the five lemma. I was able to show that $\alpha$ is surjective in the colimit but nothing else. The issue I feel like is that we are not taking colimit over a directed set so many of the good properties of direct limits that I would like to use (exactness among other things) might not hold. Is there a way to think of coverings and refinements as a poset as Hartshorne claims it is or is there some other way to solve the problem?**

Comment: I do not understand the statement "Then Hartshorne claims that the coverings of  form a partially ordered set which I don't agree with as we can have non-identity refinements of a covering." How does the existence of non-identity refinements of a covering prevent the collection of all coverings from being a partially ordered set? Every covering is a refinement of itself, which gives reflexivity. If two coverings $A$ and $B$ are refinements of each other, then they are equal, giving antisymmetry. And if $A$ is a refinement of $B$ and $B$ a refinement of $C$, then $A$ is a refinement of $C$.

Comment: "We are not taking a colimit over a directed set"... any two coverings have a common refinement, so the set **is** directed.

Comment: Well maybe it was not well said but the issue is we can have two coverings, each a refinement of the other but still the coverings are not equal. For examples open balls and open cubes in R^n.

I thought partially ordered should be part of the definition of directed set, as it is in the exercises in Atiyah McDonald where I learned about many of the properties of directed limits (page 32).

Comment: So at worst you have a pre-order, and you can easily obtain a partial order by moding out by the equivalence relation "are refinements of each other"; this will respect the properties you want so it is not a real obstacle. Yes, directed sets are partially ordered, but again, once you  mod out by that equivalence relation, you are golden.

Comment: But even if you don't want to mod out by that relation, your final  issue is not really a problem: the "good properties of direct limits" generally derive from the fact that for all $x,y$, there exists a $z$ with $x\leq z$ and $y\leq z$. You definitely have *that* for coverings.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I'm going to think about the quotenting out, I guess I would have to check that the functor $\mathfrak{U}\mapsto \breve{H}^\bullet(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{F})$ is well defined out of the quotient.\\

About your last comment. I tried to prove some properties of colimits only using  the property you mentioned but was not able to do it all. In particular I could not prove exactness, do you know if partial order is necessary for colimits to be exact?

Comment: I would need to take a careful look, and it's been a while since I did sheafs/schemes (and never did much with cohomology/homology), I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks again Arturo, the method of quotienting out and turn the set of coverings into a poset worked! If you have a refinement from one covering $\mathfrak{U}$ to itself it induces a chain map on $\breve{C}^\bullet(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{F})$ which turns out to be homotopic to the identity and therefore the functor $\mathfrak{U}\mapsto \breve{H}^\bullet(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{F})$ is well defined out of the quotient category!

Comment: Feel free to write up an answer to your own question. Passing to the partial order induced by the pre-order is a pretty typical "trick".